# Why does this code cause "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"?

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

```
dispatch_semaphore_t aSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);        
dispatch_semaphore_wait(aSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(aSemaphore);
```

When the program runs to **dispatch_release(aSemaphore)**, it will cause "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION", and then crash. Why?

Comment: Do you use ARC in your project?

Comment: ARC shouldn't be relevant to this code.

Comment: For other readers: this is trivially reproducible in 10.7, using the code the OP provides. It does not reproduce if the `_wait` is removed (including if `_wait` is replaced with `_signal` for instance). I'm hesitant to believe there's a bug in something so basic, but I am currently at a loss for why this would be illegal.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I tried this code and it does indeed die with illegal instruction. So I did some digging and found that it's dying in _dispatch_semaphore_dispose. So let's look at what that is (ARMv7 here, because it's easy to understand!):

```
__dispatch_semaphore_dispose:
000040a0            b590        push    {r4, r7, lr}
000040a2            4604        mov     r4, r0
000040a4            af01        add     r7, sp, #4
000040a6        e9d40108        ldrd    r0, r1, [r4, #32]
000040aa            4288        cmp     r0, r1
000040ac            da00        bge.n   0x40b0
000040ae            defe        trap
...
```

It dies at 0x40ae, which is a duff instruction put there so that it crashes if the `bge.n` doesn't make us branch to jump over it.

The reason it's failing is because `r0` must be less than `r1`. `r0` and `r1` are loaded from the memory at `r4 + 32` which having gone back up the stack to figure it out I *think* `r4` is `aSemaphore` in the example code, i.e. the thing passed into `dispatch_semaphore_release`. The `+ 32` signifies it is reading 32 bytes into the struct that `aSemaphore` is pointing to (it's a pointer to a `dispatch_semaphore_s` struct). So overall what it's doing it reading 4 bytes from `aSemaphore + 32` and putting them into `r0` and reading 4 bytes from `aSemaphore + 36` and putting them into `r1`.

The compare is then effectively comparing the value of `aSemaphore + 32` and `aSemaphore + 36`. Reading what `dispatch_semaphore_create` does I can see that it stores the value passed in to both `aSemaphore + 32` and `aSemaphore + 36`. I also found that `dispatch_semaphore_wait` and `dispatch_semaphore_signal` touch the value at `aSemaphore + 32`, to increment and decrement it. This means that the reason it's breaking is because the current value of the semaphore is less than the value passed into `dispatch_semaphore_create`. So you can't dispose of a semaphore when the current value is less than the value it was created with.

If you've read to here and understood my ramblings then well done! Hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

It's probably better to look at the source (pointed out by JustSid) here - http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-187.7/src/semaphore.c - looking at the `_dispatch_semaphore_dispose` function we see:

```
if (dsema->dsema_value < dsema->dsema_orig) {
    DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH("Semaphore/group object deallocated while in use");
}
```

So, yes, there you go, that's why it crashes!

Comment: Here is the source file which includes `_dispatch_semaphore_dispose()`http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-187.7/src/semaphore.c Should be easier to read and also includes some nice text about why it dies.

Comment: Yeh you're totally right that the source is a better place to look. I was just seeing the disassembly whilst stopped in GDB so I thought I'd dig from there, but looking at the code it makes it fairly clear what's going on!

Comment: Why is it that you don't see "Semaphore/group object deallocated while in use" in the logs anywhere?

Comment: @bandejapaisa - Because if you look in this file - http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-187.7/src/internal.h - you'll see that `DISPATCH_CLIENT_CRASH` is defined as `_dispatch_set_crash_log_message` which is defined as nothing. I guess that's there so that a developer can set the define to actually print something during debug.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, helps me a lot! But I suggest you put your results/main points at the top of your answer. I am pretty sure tons of people did not vote up for you because they did not make to the bottom of your answer.

Comment: The deduction is simply so beautiful.

Answer (score 26):

Somewhat more succinct answer:  You are creating the semaphore with the wrong value, it should be zero.  Creating it with a value of 1 means you are later releasing a semaphore that's still "in use" and GCD is deliberately generating an illegal instruction in order to help you debug the fact that you have a semaphore with more waiters on it.

Comment: Thanks for the 4-line version. Put another way - make sure you `dispatch_semaphore_create()` with an initial value that is <= the value you expect the semaphore to have when you `dispatch_release()` it.  If this means doing a `dispatch_semaphore_signal()` immediately after creating it, so be it.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a semaphore with zero value, but I believe it will be just useless. I had a semaphore field in a class which caused it to crash at deinitialisation. This is how I fixed it (Swift code):

```
deinit {
  while (dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) != 0) {}
}
```

A rather awkward patch, but it works!

Comment: Doesn't this introduce a race condition, if another thread starts waiting on the semaphore right after this loop exits but before ARC calls `_dispatch_semaphore_dispose`?